# Matlab replace consecutive zero value with others value

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have this matrix:

```
A = [92    92    92    91    91    91   146   146   146     0
      0     0   112   112   112   127   127   127    35    35
     16    16   121   121   121    55    55    55   148   148
      0     0     0    96    96     0     0     0     0     0
      0    16    16    16   140   140   140     0     0     0]
```

How can I replace consecutive zero value with shuffled consecutive value from matrix B?

```
B = [3 3 3 5 5 6 6 2 2 2 7 7 7]
```

The required result is some matrix like this:

```
A = [92    92    92    91    91    91   146   146   146    0
      6     6   112   112   112   127   127   127    35   35
     16    16   121   121   121    55    55    55   148  148
      7     7     7    96    96     5     5     3     3    3
      0    16    16    16   140   140   140     2     2    2]
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'shuffled consecutive values' from B? In your example it looks as if you have randomly chosen a value that occurs in B and then 'used up' all elements of B having that value to substitute for a particular run of zeroes in A. But does the run of substitute values have to match the length of the run of zeroes if possible? For example, would it be OK for the fourth row of the result to be `5   5   3   96  96  3   3   7   7   7`?

Comment: No, subtitute value from B with same number must be consecutive. Can you give me a solution?thank you @nekomatic
and it would be ok if not all values ​​from B can be distributed

Answer (score 1):

You simply can do it like this:

```
[M,N]=size(A);

for i=1:M
  for j=1:N
    if A(i,j)==0
        A(i,j)=B(i+j);
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: i've tried and the code results :Attempted to access B(14); index out of bounds because numel(B)=13

Comment: it is just because the sequence B you have written down is smaller than the numbers of zeros you have in your matrix. Try to extend B equal or larger than the numbers of your zeros.

Comment: This will replace **all** zero values in A with values from B, not just consecutive ones which is what the asker wants. Also the request was for the values from B to be 'shuffled'.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly from what you've described, your solution is going to need the following steps:

- Loop over the rows of your matrix, e.g. `for row = 1:size(A, 1)`
- Loop over the elements of each row, identify where each run of zeroes starts and store the indices and the length of the run. For example you might end up with a matrix like: `consecutiveZeroes = [ 2  1  2 ; 4  1  3 ; 4  6  5 ; 5  8  3 ]` indicating that you have a run at (2, 1) of length 2, a run at (4, 1) of length 3, a run at (4, 6) of length 5, and a run at (5, 8) of length 3.
- Now loop over the elements of B counting up how many elements there are of each value. For example you might store this as `replacementValues = [ 3  3 ; 2  5 ; 2  6 ; 3  2 ; 3  7 ]` meaning three 3's, two 5's, two 6's etc.
- Now take a row from your `consecutiveZeroes` matrix and randomly choose a row of `replacementValues` that specifies the same number of elements, replace the zeroes in `A` with the values from `replacementValues`, and delete the row from `replacementValues` to show that you've used it.
- If there isn't a row in `replacementValues` that describes a long enough run of values to replace one of your runs of zeroes, find a combination of two or more rows from `replacementValues` that will work.

You can't do this with just a single pass through the matrix, because presumably you could have a matrix A like `[ 15 7  0  0  0  0  0  0  3 ; 2  0  0  0  5  0  0  0  9 ]` and a vector B like `[ 2  2  2  3  3  3  7  7  5  5  5  5 ]`, where you can only achieve what you want if you use the four 5's and two 7's and not the three 2's and three 3's  to substitute for the run of six zeroes, because you have to leave the 2's and 3's for the two runs of three zeroes in the next row. The easiest approach if efficiency is not critical would probably be to run the algorithm multiple times trying different random combinations until you get one that works - but you'll need to decide how many times to try before giving up in case the input data actually has no solution.

If you get stuck on any of these steps I suggest asking a new, more specific question.